# Where can I find a manpage for arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld, let alone a well-written one, that includes -rpath and -rpath-link?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, arm, cross-compiling

I ran arm-linux-gnueabihf-ldd on my ELF files (one from Cygwin--don't ask--and one from Ubuntu), and despite having gotten rid of warnings on the Ubuntu one by including -rpath-link, which I assumed was making a dynamic dependency static, given the ambiguity of the elusive manpage where I read it, dll still shows ld-linux.so.3 as one of the 5 unresolved, but the linker never whined about the other four!  The path was, in this case, to a local copy installed through apt-get.

This waste of time caused the host to complain "not found" (meaning, as I later discovered, that the ELF file WAS found, but unnamed libraries weren't).  The fact that the host machine has most of these in /lib and the rest in /usr/lib made me think that -rpath and/or -rpath-link were supposed to tell it where to look on the host machine for their resolution, as if the host machine isn't smart enough to know where it keeps libraries.

I'm not looking for anything "higher-level" (i.e., more opaque) than simple arm-linux-gnueabihf-ld options (or, by extension, arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ options) that are clear enough in their use and don't cause messages like:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-rpath’
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-rpath’
```

when I know damned well it recognized "-rpath" in a different context and it's complaining that it can't find paths, which are useless to the host machine, on the build machine!

Comment: Did you mean `ld` or `ldd`?

Comment: ldd is the utility for finding unresolved externals that will require dynamic libraries.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but you write one in the title and use another in the body of your question.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [`man ld`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ld.1.html)?

The full documentation is in the [binutils manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/index.html), which you can read using `info ld`.

> -rpath-link, which I assumed was making a dynamic dependency static

No, it tells the linker where to find indirect shared library dependencies, so it can check them to be sure that there are no unresolved references.

> . The fact that the host machine has most of these in /lib and the rest in /usr/lib made me think that -rpath and/or -rpath-link were supposed to tell it where to look on the host machine for their resolution

No.

`-rpath` adds a path to the executable, so that at run-time the dynamic loader will look for shared library dependencies in that path **at run-time**. This is one way to specify paths to shared libraries, long with `ldconfig`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` etc. (see [ld.so(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) for details).

`-rpath-link` tells the linker where to look for shared library dependencies **at link-time**, but doesn't affect how dependencies are found at run-time.

You can't pass `-rpath` to `g++` because it's an option for the linker and `g++` doesn't understand it. Use `-Wl,-rpath` to tell `g++` to pass it to the linker.

Comment: Even with -Wl,"-rpath /lib" -Wl,"-rpath /usr/lib" it still complains, but with the supposedly equivalent -Wl,"-R /lib" -Wl,"-R /usr/lib" (which it also accepts without the -Wl,)  it doesn't.  It simply builds an equally useless ELF lacking a path to the dynamic libraries, same as ever.

Comment: The complaint is as follows:

/usr/lib/gcc-cross/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/ld: bad -rpath option
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Can the problem be positionally dependent as with the lack of lookahead logic in resolving static links?

Comment: It turns out that the problem was that the output of arm-linux-gnueabihf-ldd (which I ran from Cygwin, because the Ubuntu installation doesn't include it and can't find it through apt-file), and which I read through at least three times, showed me that ld-linux-armhf.so.3 was not found, and I finally realized that this is not ld-linux.so.3, so I created a soft link and now get /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found.  Finally a message that at least tells me something useful!

Comment: You were doing it wrong. The right way to use those options is `-Wl,-rpath,/lib` i.e. use commas not spaces inside quotes. Or `-Wl,rpath -Wl,/lib` (read `man gcc`). It complained about `-Wl,"-rpath /lib"` because `-rpath /lib` is not a valid option for `ld` (it needs to be two options). The version with `"-R /lib"` creates an rpath of ` /lib` i.e. with a leading space, which is never going to match anything. But you shouldn't need to set an rpath for /usr/lib, because ld.so always looks in that location anyway.

Comment: Maybe it's -rpath-link I need, since it seems to be only libc.so.6 that's still causing problems, and the one in the build environment is newer than the one on the host.  On the other hand, there's a libc_nonshared.a, but it's much smaller, and it still doesn't seem to eliminate the need for libc.so.6.  Any idea what purpose it DOES serve?

Comment: That made no difference at all.  For an experiment, I linked both ways, once with -rpath-link and once with -lc_nonshared.  Running diff afterward showed both binaries to be identical, and ldd still showed libc.so.6 to be unresolved.

An additional concern is whether a host that has a maximum GLIBC version of 2.13 can even deal with a higher version (e.g., 2.19).

Comment: You're not supposed to link to `-lc_nonshared` manually, libc.so does that automatically as needed. It's not a replacement for libc.so (it's _part_ of it). Link to `libc.a` if you don't want a dependency on libc.so, or read `man ld.so` again for how to ensure `ldd` can find it, and maybe read https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/faq.html#faq.how_to_set_paths and what it links to. And no, you can't run a binary built against glibc 2.19 on a host with glibc 2.13